# how to declare and refer to a single hash variable in several models (DRY, ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model, global-variables

I have several models that need to call a method that takes a particular hash as input. Where should I declare this hash to keep things DRY, and how can I then use it in multiple models?

The hash will be the same for all uses. Specifically, it's just a hash of connection details that I want to pass to a call to [establish_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection). I realize that that method takes a URL, though I'm still on rails 3.1, and that method was not made available until a little later.

Instead of repeating the following in five models, I just want to call something like  `establish_connection(legacy_db_connection_hash)`.

```
establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql',
  :host     => ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_HOST'],
  :username => ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
  :database => ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_NAME']
)
```

I was thinking that perhaps there's a way to do it via `/lib`, but I'm really not sure how to go about it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go into a `module`.

For example, declare a module `Foo` in the file `lib/foo.rb` (and don't forget `self.` in front of the method name):

```
module Foo
  # returns a hash of connection settings
  def self.settings
    {
      adapter: 'mysql2',
      database: ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_NAME'],
      username: ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_USERNAME'],
      password: ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
      host:     ENV['LEGACY_DATABASE_HOST']
    }
  end
end
```

`Foo.settings` will be available when you `include Foo` in your models.

Also, make sure to add the `lib` directory to `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`, so that `lib/foo.rb` is read and its contained `Foo` module is loaded:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also declare the configuration in your application.rb file

```
module Yourapp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.db_connection_config = {
     .....
    }

  end
end
```

And you can use it `Yourapp::Application.config.db_connection_config`
You can modify them in separate environment files as well, if need.

And may be instead of using establish_connection each_time you can put in a separate module in the lib module, like its suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: Or you can make an initializer with it (to keep application.rb clean)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, is it simple to modify initializer based on environments?, may be if he places his configurations in a yaml file

Comment: Yes, that's how I do it. Initializer and a yaml file.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will be pulling the actual details from environment variables (I have modified my question to show this). If someone is willing, please show me how to make an initializer for this purpose by posting an answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

#### config/initializers/profile_store.rb

```
config = YAML.load_file('config/profile_store.yml')[Rails.env]
Rails.application.config.profile_store = config.symbolize_keys
```

#### config/profile_store.yml

```
development:
  host: localhost
  prefix: dev-profile

test:
  host: localhost
  prefix: test-profile
```

You access it later with `Rails.application.config.profile_store` and in development you'll get

```
{:host => 'localhost', :prefix => 'dev-profile'}
```